# Angular - interpolating values after every forEach iteration

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm building an Angular app, and I'm trying to interpolate value of a string in every forEach iteration on an array of strings.
(quotesData is array of strings from which I'm taking values from)

My function looks like this:

```
export() {
this.quotesData.forEach(element => {
  this.quote = element;
  this.wait(1000); \\ <- manually written function to postpone next line execution for 1s
  console.log(this.quote);
});
```

}

The problem is that the value in HTML interpolation for {{quote}} doesn't get updated until the last iteration ends. However, value for this.quote is properly updated and displayed in console and in Debugger after every iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how your wait function is implemented but I guess it still running asynchronously. To troubleshoot it I would suggest increasing the time to 5000 for example and checking if the values are displayed immediately in the console or not.

Otherwise, here is a working example using async await:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<button (click)="display()" >Display</button><h1>Hello {{quote}}!</h1>`,
})
export class HelloComponent {
  quotesData: Array<string> = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
  quote: string = '';

  wait(ms) {
    return new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));
  }

  async display() {
    for (let quote of this.quotesData) {
      this.quote = quote;
      await this.wait(1000);
      console.log(this.quote);
    }
  }
}
```